# Timer is working strangely, how to fix

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am making a video game, and specifically now I want to make pseudo-animated doors.

What I mean, when the door in my game is used, it's image should change from "closed" to "open", then the game must wait for about half a second, and only then another area should be loaded.
The problem is, that timer doesn't actually wait the desired time, or at least doesn't always do so. Sometimes it lasts 500 milliseconds, as it's expected, and sometimes for shorter period of time.

**I am using following code:**

When door is used

```
            imgLockerRoomOpenDoor.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            tmrDoorOpening.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrLockerRoomDoorOpening);
            tmrDoorOpening.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
            tmrDoorOpening.Start();
```

The "tmrLockerRoomDoorOpening" code:

```
        tmrDoorOpening.Stop();

        AreaTransition();
        areaHibernation1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        areaHibernation1.IsEnabled = true;
        areaHibernation1.Margin = new Thickness(55, 31, 0, 0);
        ActionsReset();
```

Timer declaration:

```
    public static System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmrDoorOpening = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
```

AreaTransition is used to hide all game areas, so don't think its relevant.

Why does the timer works for different period of time? How can I set it to be the same?

I'll give an example.
There are two rooms.

1) I am in room 1.

2) I click on the door.

3) The door image changes to open, program waits for 1/2 of minute, then room 1 disappears and I appear in room 2.

4) I go back to room 1. The door has closed image.

5) I click on the door again, but now the open door appears for shorter period of time.

Comment: Have you tried different timers? Personally, I'd try the `System.Timers.Timer` and take advantage of the "one-shot" feature. This timer can fire once only, so you don't have to worry about stopping/restarting really. And it's also a threaded timer.

Comment: You say this timer is for one use. Will I be able to reset it, if I want to repeat the action? I don't want it to be auto-repeated, but I do want it to be repeated when I need it.

Comment: The "normal" timer is started, when the event is fired you stop it *explicitly* and then start it again when you need to. The `System.Timers.Timer` has an `AutoReset` property. If it is set to `false`, the timer will stop automatically when the event fires and you *don't have to explicitly stop it*. Of course you can at any time start it again!

Comment: you should be carefull where you call `tmrDoorOpening.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrLockerRoomDoorOpening);` Make sure you don't add a new handler every time when clicking a door. Remember you made the timer `static`. Something i personally wouldn't do in this case on the form. Are you reusing the window/page ?

Comment: @Dbuggy You're exactly right - I didn't even see the timer was declared `static`. I'd create a new instance of the timer whenver a door is hit and pass to the timer the "door instance" so the timer knows which door to handle.

Comment: What code will you recommend? I never learned c# "officially", all my knowledge is from internet.

Comment: EDIT: Yes, all actions with such a timer can be repeated.

Answer (score -1):

I see you use  tmrDoorOpening.Stop();

so the timer can't be always 500 since you stop it?

it will do 500 + the time between stop()> work > start()

Comment: Well, the OP complains about the timer interval being *shorter* than the expected 500ms. As he's using `Stop()` only in the timer event, stopping does not shorten the interval. He's **not** complaining that the timer doesn't repeatedly fire at exactly 500ms, which would be explained by the last line of your answer. He basically wants a one-shot timer that fires after 500ms. So no, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: So, I need to add a line that restarts it?

Comment: @EvgenieT No, I think Zwan misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Updated original post to give more detail.

Comment: oops it was a comment not a answer sry. By the code i don't get  a timer can give shorter result than his set, from the start() it will be 500 ms  in any condition to me and only the stop() can shorten this delay.

Comment: Hard to understand not all code is provided but reading what you try to achieve i wonder why not simply use Thread.Sleep(500) ; at least you are sure what you wait.

Comment: @Zwan You are right about this, but that's also what's puzzling the OP :-)

Comment: @Zwan Probably because he doesn't want to block the main thread, but instead get an "event" when is pause is over.

Comment: @Torsen i know i was doing that at first when dealing with GUI but if he want a games better point him in rigth way and not use timer for anithing GUI . BackgroundWorker orDelegate is a point of interest to take in consideration for deal with GUI freeze and such or playing with timer will turn him crazy at end

Comment: @Zwan So lags resulting from putting the GUI to sleep are better than doing proper asynchronous programming? I'd love to see the games you develop... Using `Sleep` on the GUI thread is *not* the right way. Using tasks, timers, events or even background workers and threads is the right way of creating a responsive GUI, and in games even more as you don't get high FPS by blocking the game loop.

Comment: @Thorsen any click doing long stuff work async no needed to mention this    so the thread.sleep(any) can be in a backround/task/thread without bloking gui. For a easy  start click code will be worker.RunWorkerAsync(); and the pause and long stuff is made in the DoWork section and update gui in worker.RunWorkerCompleted() (that one way it have a tone...

Comment: for his probleme it look like he able to click and execute multple time the code that start()/Stop() randomly his timer and overide what he did on the first click why i point him using backgroundwork and wait it's state to be finish

Comment: @Zwan That doesn't make sense at all. Putting `Sleep` into a background task/thread doesn't have any effect unless you have an event you get when the task/thread is done. And this is *exactly* what he's doing using a timer. A threaded timer is more or less exactly what you describe. A task/thread that waits for the given amount of time and then fires an event when the pause is over. Why overcomplicate things? He's exactly right to use a timer in the first place! He may just be declaring it wrong.

Comment: ok do a game with timer ;).good luck.The proof of my point is rigth at start he can't have control on it and can't change a simple image when he want.check gamer maker comunity how they start build a simple game engine in 70% you will retrieve the background as i tell.